# Deploying and troubleshooting an API

Tags: azure, kubernetes

Good morning...

I'm a newbie to AKS, so, please go easy on me.

As a company, we are currently attempting to compare Azure Container Apps and Azure Kubernetes Services. I have successfully deployed an ACA that is up and running, no issue. Very easy actually. However, I've struggled to get the same API running in an AKS cluster (frankly, I expected more difficulties) and I'm now stuck.

After a few days of trial-and-error, I have the container deployed in an AKS cluster with a load balancer. The issue I'm having is that even with the load balancer in front of the AKS node, any requests to the API timeout. I'm guessing I haven't configured either the load balancer or maybe even my container correctly??

Does anyone have some troubleshooting tips for me?

I'll provide more information if necessary!

Thanks!

My service.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: helpservicedeployment
  name: helpservicedeployment-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    target port: 8080
  selector:
    app: helpservicedeployment
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Please, provide the service and deployment configurations

Comment: can you post the deployment yaml file?

Comment: Added my yml just in case anyone else comes across this and wants to see what I changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample of Loadbalancer yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: public-svc
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: public-app
```

PS: make suer the selector matches the labels you specify for you pod

more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard

Comment: Thank you!  I had a target port in my yaml that I removed that fixed it!  Thank you!